# How to solve ElevatedButton error in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I am new to flutter and I am developing an app in Flutter. While I am doing this, I try to add `ElevatedButton` which is the latest version of RaisedButton, and its return error and I am also not sure why. I will insert the error code image and would be grateful if someone tells me what is the reason for the error and how to solve it. Thank you

[image]

Comment: see the sample code of ElevatedButton: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButton-class.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a **child widget** (it is required in addition to **onPressed** function). Here is a sample code for Elevated Button. You can adjust it based on your needs:

```
ElevatedButton(
    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        onPrimary: Colors.white,
        primary: Color(0xffccbbd7),
        minimumSize: const Size(330,70),
        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
               Radius.circular(5),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    onPressed: () {},
    child: const Text('click'),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You Forgot the **`child`** Widget inside **`ElevatedButton`**, in this button `onPressed` and `child` widgets are **required**

Refer [**`ElevatedButton`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButton-class.html)

Try below code

```
 ElevatedButton(
     onPressed: () {
       // write your onPressed function here
       print('Button Pressed');
     },
     child: const Text('Press Me'),
 ),
```

Your result screen-> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, elevated button should have child inside. Can be text, icon or image

```
 ElevatedButton(
     onPressed: () {
       print('Tombol baru saja ditekan!');
     },
     child: const Text('Hit me!'),
 ),
```